# What are interesting and evocative words for (disgusting) throat sounds?

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

Here is my passage for example:

> “Now I can hear him through the walls hucking and sniffing,
>   expectorating and blowing all kinds of things in a grotesque,
>   unconscious, unhealthy sounding manner.”

Like the sounds a sick, mucusy person makes when trying to clear their throat.

Expectorate was the best I could find but I feel like there are some more, almost comically obscure words for this. Perhaps even some good onomatopoeias?

I think of words that might sound like gesticulate, conflagration, or 4-5 syllable equivalent to gurgle, gargle, huck or hawk.

Inventing a word like “gurgulate” would be fun here too, but I'm seeing what's out there first!

Comment: Merely a note of interest: A German friend and I heard her daughter sniffling one day, and asked the child whether she felt unwell. Her answer was "Ne, I'm only bischen snifflische." Growing up in two languages created a word, and sentence construction that was adorable, though technically improper. Snifflische was pronounced "sniff-lish-eh." Perhaps the words you seek can be built in similar ways.

Comment: This site isn't meant for getting a list of words. You need to define specific criteria that would result in a *single* word that is best suited to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One word you might use is "**tussiculation**". It's the medical word for a hacking cough.  The *hacking* aspect is built into the definition. You could use it alone or in concatenation with any number of adjectives like *chunky, wet, productive, congested, expulsive, phlegmy, and/or glutinous*. Only with reference to the latter part of your question, there is plenty of fertile ground for "invented words" among these as well.

> He tried to speak, but all that came out was another series of
>   chunky, glutinous **tussiculation(s)**.

https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/tussiculation

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/phlegm

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chunky

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glutinous

Comment: oooo- tussiculation is a great find! thanks so much! I've been playing with inventing too. I added -ing to my "gurgulate" mentioned above. That gave me the satisfying extra 4th syllable I was looking for. Gurgulating. -- do you know if there is a medical word or term for clearing your throat of mucus that's not an involuntary cough or hacking, but more the manual/intentional deep hmmmmpph hmmmphh, kind of grunt/gurgle/gargle... like the sound you make when you're about to "hock a loogie"? Though I think that might be expectorate which I already used... 

Answer (score 0):

Gollum in *The Lord of the Rings* was named for the sound he repeatedly made in his throat.